# Generate a prediction raster for a species distribution using terra::predict and caret::train ranger model

Tags: r, r-caret, terra

I've got a species distribution project going on with presence and pseudo-absence/background points. I've set up a data frame and trained a model using *caret::train* with 10 k-folds, and I'm making life easier with *method="ranger"*. So, now I've got an averaged-out ranger model.

Now, here's where I'm hitting a snag. I've got this stack raster file with bioclimatic stuff (WorldClim), orographic data (elevation, slope, and such), plus a couple of categorical rasters (Land use and geology type). The plan is to use *terra::predict* to get a raster showing presence probabilities.

But here's the catch: when I run the predict function, it's giving me trouble. It either doesn't run at all or spits out an error message about *"Missing data in columns"* I've checked, and my stack rasters are all good; they worked fine when I was using a simpler *randomForest *without k-folds.

I've tried looking for other prediction methods and played around with how I'm feeding the data, but no luck so far. Anyone got any ideas or tips to help me sort this out?

Objective:
Generate a raster of probabilities for the distribution of a species using a pseudo-absence and a RandomForest. Then use the model to predict current and future distribution only changing climatic rasters.

Example data

```
library(terra)
library(caret)
library(tuneRanger)
library(ranger)

logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
logo[75:77, ] <- NA
p <- matrix(c(48, 48, 48, 53, 50, 46, 54, 70, 84, 85, 74, 84, 95, 85, 
              66, 42, 26, 4, 19, 17, 7, 14, 26, 29, 39, 45, 51, 56, 46, 38, 31, 
              22, 34, 60, 70, 73, 63, 46, 43, 28), ncol=2)

a <- matrix(c(22, 33, 64, 85, 92, 94, 59, 27, 30, 64, 60, 33, 31, 9,
              99, 67, 15, 5, 4, 30, 8, 37, 42, 27, 19, 69, 60, 73, 3, 5, 21,
              37, 52, 70, 74, 9, 13, 4, 17, 47), ncol=2)
xy <- rbind(cbind(1, p), cbind(0, a))
e <- extract(logo, xy[,2:3])
v <- data.frame(cbind(pa=xy[,1], e))
```

Make the model

```
v_NA_kNN <- caret::preProcess(v, method="bagImpute")
v_rf <- predict(v_NA_kNN,v)

v_rf$pa <- as.factor(v_rf$pa)
levels(v_rf$pa) <- c("Pres","Abs")

rf.task <-  makeClassifTask(data = v_rf, target = "pa")
res <- tuneRanger(rf.task, measure = list(multiclass.brier), num.trees = 1e+02,
                  num.threads = 4, iters = 20, save.file.path = NULL)

fitControl <- caret::trainControl(
  method = "repeatedcv", 
  number = 5,             
  repeats = 5,            
  allowParallel = T,
  classProbs=T,
  returnData = T,
  savePredictions = "final"
)

ranger_model <- caret::train(
  v_rf[,-1],     
  as.factor(v_rf$pa), #This way factor is not separated by levels
  method = "ranger",
  trControl = fitControl,
  tuneGrid = expand.grid(mtry = res$recommended.pars[,1],
                         min.node.size = res$recommended.pars[,2],
                         splitrule = "gini"),
  num.trees = 1e+02,
  num.threads = 4,
  importance = 'impurity'
)
```

predict

```
predfun <- function(...) predict(...)$predictions
x <- terra::predict(logo, ranger_model, fun=predfun)
# Error in predict(...)$predictions : 
#  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
# Called from: fun(model, d, ...)
```

Comment: When asking a R question, please include a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example* (see my answer, the R help files, and the Q&A on this site for examples).

Comment: Thank you for adding an example, but it is not self-contained. That is, you need to change your script so that we can run it with the example data that you provide. (see my example; do not provide files).

Comment: I do not fully understand how thats gonna help my specific case, but you got it.

Comment: I hope this is clear now.

Comment: Yeah, I could get the data that I want. Thank you so much. I will remender this next time I post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run `terra::predict` with default arguments you get:

```
x <- terra::predict(logo, ranger_model)
#Error: Missing data in columns: red, green, blue.
```

You can fix that by using `na.rm=TRUE`

```
x <- terra::predict(logo, ranger_model, na.rm=TRUE)
```

You do not need to supply a specialized predict function because the caret predict function returns a simple vector

```
predict(ranger_model, logo[1:4])
#[1] Pres Pres Pres Pres
#Levels: Pres Abs
```

In contrast, if you used the predict function from "ranger", you would get a list, and in that case you could use

```
predfun <- function(...) predict(...)$predictions
x <- terra::predict(logo, ranger_model, fun=predfun, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Sorry, I update it.